# How to show invisible characters in webstorm

Tags: webstorm, invisible, hidden-characters

As many of you have probably come across the problem of cutting and pasting some code, which comes along with it some hidden characters often resulting in the dreaded `UNEXPECTED_TOKEN_ILLEGAL`

Is there a way within Webstorm to show/hide invisible characters?

Answer (score 2):

Install and use **Zero Width Characters locator plugin**-- it can detect quite few invisible characters (e.g. UTF-8 BOOM sequence, non-breakable space etc).

It is implemented as separate inspection with highest (Error) severity so will be easy to spot or check whole folder/project just for these issues.

---

There is a ticket (Feature Request) to have an option to show invisible characters in editor.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115572 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.